# Getting object array values based on value of range slider

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, range

The following function is designed to set labels 1, 2, and 3 to be the values in the array of the object based on the value of a range slider:

```
function repaymentOptions() {
  let repayments = {
    "2000": [100, 200, 300],
    "3000": [100, 200, 300],
    "4000": [100, 200, 300]
  };
  let label1 = $('#label1');
  let label2 = $('#label2');
  let label3 = $('#label3');
  label1.textContent = repayments[$("#range").val()][0] + " per 26 week";
  label2.textContent = repayments[$("#range").val()][1] + " per 39 week";
  label3.textContent = repayments[$("#range").val()][2] + " per 52 week";
}
```

So if the range slider value were to be 2000, then the labels 1 2 and 3 should be 100, 200, 300 respectively.

At the moment I am getting the error:
`Cannot read property '0' of undefined`

Answer (score 0):

That error means that `$("#range").val()` isn't returning `"2000"`, `"3000"`, or `"4000"`. If it were, that code would work (though there's no reason to repeat the DOM lookup and property lookup three times).

You've said in a comment that the slider will have other values, such as `"2250"`. That's the problem. Your `repayments` object doesn't have a property called `"2250"`.

The primary fix will be to ensure that all values the slider can provide are also properties of the object, or to change how you select what set of values from the object to use.

Here's an example that at least doesn't throw the error when the value from the slider doesn't match a property:

```
function repaymentOptions() {
    let repayments = {"2000":[100,200,300],"3000":[100,200,300],"4000":[100,200,300]};
    let label1 = $('#label1');
    let label2 = $('#label2');
    let label3 = $('#label3');
    let options = repayments[$("#range").val()];
    if (options) {
        label1.textContent = options[0] + " per 26 week";
        label2.textContent = options[1] + " per 39 week";
        label3.textContent = options[2] + " per 52 week";
    } else {
        // Handle the fact the slider doesn't match anything
    }
}
```

You haven't answered my question about what you want to do with `"2250"`, so it's hard to give you anything more specific than that.

Comment: Hey T.J, ultimately my slider will always have values that match the items in the array, so no need for the if and else, but I appreciate you contributing that.
I did a console log of the range slider values and it is giving me 2000, 2250, 2500, etc. so I am not sure what is wrong when the range slider value matches the objects. I removed the quotes from the "2000" "3000" in the object, but that did not help. Any ideas?

Comment: @user9951515 - The problem is that your object has no property called `2250`, so when the range slider is `2250`, `repayments[$("#range").val()]` is `undefined`. Is it your goal to use the values for the `2000` property when the value of the slider is `2250`?

Comment: Is that what is breaking it? I put in your if else and it is still not working

Comment: @user9951515 - Yes, when you look up a property, the name has to match exactly. `"2250"` doesn't match `"2000"` or `"3000"` or `"4000"`. And if you actually did put in the `else`, it would not have the error you've described. If you're still seeing that error, you don't have the check above implemented correctly. Separately: You didn't answer my question above.

Comment: Hi TJ, 
Sorry for ignoring your question, I did not see it. At the end of the day, each of my values in the slider will have a correlating value in the array. So your if else statement will not be needed in the final version. It's just that there are a lot of values so for testing I did not bother with them.
Unfortunately your code is still not working for me, there is no console error, however the text of the labels is not changing.

Comment: Do the quotes need to be around the object property in the array?

Comment: @user9951515 - Of course the text in the labels isn't changing, that's the whole point of the `if`. :-) For the values that don't have corresponding properties in `repayments`, you don't **have** text to change the labels to. The code would be fine as-is if all the values were in `repayments`. The sole problem is that they aren't. (That said, I would do the `let options = repayments[$("#range").val()];` thing rather than repeating all that work three times.)

Comment: @user9951515 *"Do the quotes need to be around the object property in the array?"* Those properties aren't in an array. `{}` creates an object, not an array. The quotes that you have are optional, but with or without them the property names are strings. When you look up the property in the object (`repayments[...]`), if you supply a number, the number is converted to string. So it doesn't matter whether the slider returns `2000` (the number) or `"2000"` (the string).

Comment: Hmmm, *"The quotes that you have are optional..."* could be confusing. :-) In an object literal like the one you have (`let repayments = { }`), you have properties listed as `propertyname: propertyvalue`. Properties names are always strings or Symbols (don't worry about Symbols for now.), and you're allowed to write them in several ways: 1. An unquoted identifier like `x` (`x: "bar"`). 2. A quoted value (`"y": "bar"`). 3. An unquoted numeric literal (`2000: "bar"`). Those all produce properties with strings as names (`"x"`, `"y"`, and `"2000"`). When you're looking up a property name using...

Comment: ...brackets notation, what you pass it is converted to string (unless it's a Symbol). So `repayments[2000]` and `repayments["2000"]` and `repayments[2 * 1000]` all look up the property named `"2000"`.